# Raspberry pi 3 analogue (headphone jack) audio output and usb microphone as input

Tags: usb, audio

How can I use the default audio analogue (headphone jack) output and as input a usb microphone together for voice recognition? I want to use the onboard audio output and record from a usb microphone, but I don`t know how to configure it...

I have one Raspberry Pi 3 with the latest Raspbian

Comment: Do you want to record the audio outputted by the same device? Why?

Comment: No , i want to record my voice with the usb microphone , and when Jasper speeks to hear the audio from the dafualt analog audio output from Raspberry , i don`t have a usb audio card just a usb microphone

Answer (score 1):

Long delay in answering but my solution was to simply write two different .asoundrc files, one for the USB audio IO and one for the jack.  In my case I was going from mic to audio and back again programmatically (think Siri or Jasper-like application).  When I want to output to the speaker, I just load the jack rc file [in python: os.system('sudo cp .asoundrc_analog .asoundrc'), output the file and then reload the usb rc file immediately thereafter to be ready to record.  Rinse and repeat.